# What is the difference between Collaborative Filtering and Collaborative Quality Filtering?

Tags: filtering, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am currently looking into Collaborative Quality Filtering and was just wondering, What is the difference between Collaborative Filtering and Collaborative Quality Filtering? It seems to me that they are both exactly the same thing (different names for the same thing). Do they have seperate definitions or something?

I have tried to search google for "Collaborative Quality Filtering" and it only returns 56 results, none of which clarify anything for me.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

From [this paper](http://maya.cs.depaul.edu/webkdd04/final/traupman.pdf)

> Unlike standard collaborative
>   filtering, Collaborative Quality Filtering (CQF) systems do not create
>   personal recommendations for users.
>   Instead, they use individual reviews
>   to estimate the underlying quality of
>   the item being reviewed. Clearly,
>   collaborative quality filtering is
>   less useful for items where people’s
>   tastes tend to differ, such as movies,
>   books, and music. However, for items
>   where there is agreement about what
>   constitutes quality, it can be a more
>   accurate method of estimating quality
>   than the simple or Bayesian means in
>   common use today.

Thats a specific usage but IMO it is enough to show the difference between them.